# Chrome and Firefox shows "<!--[if IE]-->" / IE ONLY code

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, if-statement, conditional-comments

Both Firefox and chrome insist to execute  this code :

```
<!--[if IE]>
<p>Internet Explorer only code</p>
<![endif]-->
```

And also this one:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
Special instructions for IE 7 here
<![endif]-->
```

They show the IF IE content like the IF was not there ... What to do ?

Comment: Please post a *minimal* HTML example (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net) that  reproduces the issue described. I suspect that the above is either not being rendered in the HTML markup or the markup otherwise contains a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

These specials instructions work only in the header, usually to load special `script` or `link` tags

Comment: And if I want to do them inside PHP I remember to do this in past

Comment: I have noticed that in other area of the code it does work - Problem solved - Thank you